# Website is freezing and cant login to cpanel

Tags: php

I am new to php web dev and I have been working on a website recently... It was working great on my local server but when I put it up on an actual server it started running really slow until it finally gave up and now I can't even access the website.. or cpanel... I have been doing a little research thinking maybe it had to do with and overload of sql queries but I can't seem to find any...

My site contains a lot of javascript and ajax calls to php scripts which fetch data from the database... (new notifications, messages) and I have stuff like:

```
//QUESTION RETRIEVAL FOR HOME FEED 
  $(function(){
    $r = setTimeout(alive_retrieval,100);
  });
  function alive_retrieval(){
    $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:"php/alive_questions.php",
      success:function(data){
        $("#alive_question.content").html(data);
      }
    });
    $r = setTimeout(alive_retrieval,100);
  }
  $(function(){
    $t = setTimeout(question_retrieval,100);
  });
```

This just keeps calling the alive_retrieval function over and over, which I am guessing could cause my site to be slow...

I don't kno what to post in order to help (code, the link to my website.. or w/e) Please tell me what I should give you guys so you might be able to see what is happening...

When I go to my site address this error pops up from my hosting provider:

```
Website you were trying to visit was disabled for 5 minutes, because it received over 20% of total server requests.
It means that this website was using over 20% of processor resources, which is above allowed limit.
Website was temporary disabled to protect server from overloading and other websites on server.
```

Comment: talk to your host, check the logs. your chosen hosting plan may not be appropriate for your website, but to many variables to be able to tell

Comment: The interval you have 100 millisecods, means your code would be attempting to refresh the data it wants TEN times every second! So its a good bet that increasing the interval to something over 1 minute wold be a good idea for starters. Websites are supposed to be EVENT driven, the event occurs and a request is made. if no one is requesting (viewing) a feed/page then why try to download/refresh it hundreds of times every minute? @100 milli seconds i make that 600 requests per minute!

Comment: lol ok yea didn't really realize the time thing there... but what if I wanted to have a checker so they don't have to refresh the pages to see if they have a new notification...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the Javascript you were running was trying to reload the page 10 times per second (by setting timeouts of 100 milliseconds). This is totally unreasonable -- changing that to once every 10 seconds (10000 milliseconds) might be more acceptable.

Comment: I would like to try this but I can't even get into the cpanel to upload... any ideas on that?

Comment: That did it, does sending requests like that really make a site crash? I mean what if I have 300 users using the site next wont that make it crash? What should I look into reading to learn about this stuff?

Comment: your site did not crash is was disable by the host for breaching the usage policy.